# Why does ListableBeanFactory not consider the parent context by default?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

It is documented that, in contrast to the interface `BeanFactory`, the interface `ListableBeanFactory` does not consider beans of a parent application context. For the latter to work, the advise is to use `BeanFactoryUtils`.

While the advise works in ones own code, it does not when using some Spring integrations. E.g., Spring MVC does not find rest controllers in the parent context. I know that for this specific case, the desired behavior can be enabled by using [this setter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html#setDetectHandlersInAncestorContexts(boolean)). However, other features might lack this possibility.

In order to achieve the mentioned behavior by default, I implemented a `ParentConsideringBeanFactory` that extends the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` by looking up beans in the parent context as well by default. I then configured this bean factory as the default one when building the application contexts. By now, this solution works quite well. But I don't know if it silently breaks something, now or in the future.

The current way seems to be a design decision and I would like to get insights about the reasoning behind it. My concrete questions would be:

1. Why does Spring not consider the parent context for methods of `ListableBeanFactory` by default?
2. What could happen when changing this default behavior with the mentioned `ParentConsideringBeanFactory`?

Comment: You don't need it, as you should be using an `ApplicationContext` in the first place, which can have a parent/child relationship and will use it. That has been the case since Spring 0.9/1.0 and still is (that is where the whole hierarchy thing comes from in the first place using a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` (or multiple dispatcherservlets). That way you had 1 datasource for multiple servlets which works out-of-the-box. The Spring MVC case is a different unrelated one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know that `ApplicationContext` inherits the interfaces `BeanFactory` and `ListableBeanFactory` and can therefore be asked for beans as well. However, as far as I understood, the common implementations of `ApplicationContext` delegate calls to these methods to their bean factory which is a `DefaultListableBeanFactory` by default. Also, the JavaDoc of `ListableBeanFactory` states that parent contexts are not considered. Have I overlooked some aspect?